# Getting unsafe app blocked while updating the flutter released apk?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I have published my flutter released apk on play store and installed into my device. Then I have done some updates and generated new released apk using the same keystore file which is not updated to play store yet.

Now I have shared that apk to my mobile.

But while updating/installing it to my mobile directly by that shared released apk to my mobile getting the:

"unsafe app blocked"
or install anyway

Why this is not updating or unsafe because I have generated using same keystore? Or it is possible to update the play store apk by downloaded apk?

Comment: The message sounds more like your app was blocked by Play protect. Often you can not really understand why it blocks apps, some weeks ago it even blocked one of Googles own apps...